# replacing an object of a collection using spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to return a new columns object with updated tabs array and replace this object the existing one in my datasource. Here's the relevant part. Below, uses spread, however, it adds my object to the end of the columns. How can I make it replace the existing column? 
Thanks!

```
newState = {
  columns: [
    { id: column.id, title: column.title, tabs: removedTabs },
    ...state.columns
  ],
    columnOrder: ["chromeTabs", ...state.columnOrder]
};
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/8nmrnmwlw9)

Comment: Clone and then explicitly set it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newState = {
  columns: [
    ...state.columns.filter(item => item.id !== column.id),
    { id: column.id, title: column.title, tabs: removedTabs }
  ],
    columnOrder: [...state.columnOrder.filter(item => item !== 'chromeTabs'), "chromeTabs"]
};
```

return a filtred array and your new item, should do what you expect, using spread operator to replace existing item only work on object (because key are unique) not array.

```js
const obj = {
  cool: "is it cool ?"
};

console.log({ ...obj, cool: "definetly" });
```